# itamae でリモートの実行結果をレシピ内で使う方法

Tags: itamae

リモートでコマンドを実行してその結果を変数として使いたいです

```
host_name = `hostname`.strip
```

のような感じのことを

```
execute 'hostname'
```

の出力に対して行う方法はないでしょうか

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
host_name = run_command('hostname').stdout.strip
```

でできました